# ASP MVC 2 unedited fields come back null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Controller with two Edit methods (see below). When I submit the view, any property in quoteOption that is not posted back via an input control is empty.  For example, in quoteOption I have quoteOptionID - which I don't display or make editable.  That property is empty (set to 0) in quoteOptionToUpdate.  If I add a textbox for QuoteOptionID then it works.

```
public ActionResult Edit(long id)
{
    quoteOption = quoteService.GetQuoteOptionByID(id); 
    return View("Create",quoteOption);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(QuoteOption quoteOptionToUpdate)
{
    quoteService.UpdateQuoteOption(quoteOptionToUpdate);  //quoteOptionID is null
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Are you using a LINQ2SQL DataContext?

Comment: under the hood yes, but the quoteOption object is a plain object that is passed in and out of a service layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typical applications, you need to transmit the field value back and forth due to the statelessness of the web. For example, you could simply put the value in a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="QuoteOptionID" value="...." />
```

Note that this will expose the ID to the user.

You could also store certain session information on the server side and use a custom model binder so your app effectively knows what the user last did, but I would not recommend that.

Comment: I thought the data would somehow come back but I guess not.  This has prompted me to switch to surogate keys (guids) for security.

Comment: I am also  having the same problem: textbox values, either edited or not edited come back as null. The textboxes are declared using the Html helper method like @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstName).  I do not have private setter for Employee.FirstName string property. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you write it like this you will get the id separately (as it only exists in the querystring and not in your form).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(QuoteOption quoteOptionToUpdate, Long id)
```

In the edit-method you can then assign the id to the quoteOptionToUpdate:

```
quoteOptionToUpdate.Id = id;
```